# How to edit stored value in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I am storing some string value in NSUserDefaults,

In the next button click I need to edit stored value and save new string in the place of old string.

How can I do this.

Can any one please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: newStringValue forKey: kMyKey];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"Password"]; 

[prefs setObject:@"" forKey:@"Password"];

NSString  *passwordStr = [prefs stringForKey:@"Password"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```